# How to reduce the spacing between the checkbox and the column and in between the columns in custom data table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, primereact

I am using prime react to create my reusable custom data table.

[image]

There is so much unnecessary space:

- in between the columns and
- in between the checkbox and expander icon and
- in between  expander and the columns. I want to reduce that space. I am using prime react columns.

  ```
    {checkbox && (
          <Column
          key="checkbox"
          header={
            <Checkbox
              className="custom-checkbox"
              checked={selectAll}
              onChange={() => this.toggleAllRows()}
            />
          }
          body={(rowData) => (
            <Checkbox
              className="custom-checkbox"
              checked={selectedRows.some((row) => row.id === rowData.id)}
              onChange={() => this.toggleRow(rowData)}
            />
          )}
          className="p-frozen-column"
        />
        )}
        {this.props.includeExpander &&
  ```

  <Column expander style={{ width: '3em' }} /> }

I tried reducing the margin, padding everything. But nothing is working out. Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!